# How to Identify Clipping Mask using javascript without ratios for photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-script

I want to find all clipping mask layer from psd. but problem is how can we identify clipping mask layers in psd currently I'm using below code.

I tried this [How to identify clipping masks in Photoshop using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057122/how-to-identify-clipping-masks-in-photoshop-using-javascript)

But it is not working.

```
for (var x = 0; x < layers.length; x++) {
    var layerindex = layers[x];
    doc.activeLayer = doc.artLayers[x];
    var ref = new ActionReference();

    ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") ); 

    var desc = executeActionGet(ref);

    if(desc.hasKey(charIDToTypeID('GrpL'))){

        alert("this is Clipping Mask Layer");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var doc = activeDocument,
    layers = activeDocument.layers;

for (var x = 0; x < layers.length; x++)
{
    doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[x];
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt"));
    var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
    if (desc.hasKey(charIDToTypeID('Grup')) && desc.getBoolean(charIDToTypeID('Grup')))
    {
        alert("this is Clipping Mask Layer: " + doc.activeLayer.name);
    }
}
```